# How to fix the code empty cell when click the button to input data

Tags: excel, vba

When I click the button to input data while data is blank. The 'blank' input data will be added to the table and on the output table, it will appears as a blank row. How can I fix this problem? If I only want just value or text that the user input to appear in the output table.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set AddNew1 = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(40, 0)
Set AddNew2 = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

Set newrow = wks.ListObjects("List").ListRows.Add

With newrow
    .Range(1) = wks.Range("M4")
    .Range(2) = wks.Range("N4")

End With



For i = 1 To 2

AddNew1.Cells(i, j) = wks.Range("M4").Cells(i, j)

Next i


wks.Range("M4:Q8") = ""

End Sub
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMdqM.png)

Comment: Where do you declare `newrow`? I assume that's a range? And then `newrow.range(1)` would be the ...first cell?

Comment: Yes, but when data not include in M4 and N5 then I click the button , The column will have empty cell in Column D and E. How to do empty cell will not happen when I click button?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set AddNew1 = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(40, 0)
Set AddNew2 = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

If wks.Range("M4") <> "" And wks.Range("N4") <> "" Then

    Set newrow = wks.ListObjects("List").ListRows.Add

    With newrow
        .Range(1) = wks.Range("M4")
        .Range(2) = wks.Range("N4")

    End With



    For i = 1 To 2

    AddNew1.Cells(i, j) = wks.Range("M4").Cells(i, j)

    Next i


    wks.Range("M4:Q8") = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no a clear question... I will just assume (Sorry, I can not make comments)
I am assuming that you are trying to introduce whatever data you have on M4-N4 Cells to your Range AddNew1. So try this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set wks = Worksheets(1)

For i = 1 To 2
    wks.Cells(65356 + i, 13).Value2 = wks.Cells(4, 12 + i).Value2
Next i

With wks
    Range("M4:Q8").Value2 = ""
End With
```

If you are trying to keep the information with the same setup (M and N columns)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set wks = Worksheets(1)


wks.Cells(65356 , 13).Value2 = wks.Cells(4, 13).Value2
wks.Cells(65356 , 14).Value2 = wks.Cells(4, 14).Value2


With wks
    Range("M4:Q8").Value2 = ""
End With
```

If you are not interested to copy empty cells, place a condition.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set wks = Worksheets(1)

If (wks.Cells(4, 13).Value2 <> "") & (wks.Cells(4, 14).Value2 <> "") Then
    wks.Cells(65356 , 13).Value2 = wks.Cells(4, 13).Value2
    wks.Cells(65356 , 14).Value2 = wks.Cells(4, 14).Value2
End If

With wks
    Range("M4:Q8").Value2 = ""
End With
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Anyhow, AddNew1 and AddNew2 should be defined as Range, newrow as ListRow, i and j as Long and ListRow.Range will not work. Could you give a little bit more information regarding what is your data an expected results?